# Possible to re-calculate a response surface design experiment in R from old results in StatEase?

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to replicate some results which was produced using an old StatEase 6 software several years ago. I had done a constrained design, response surface model, D-optimal design.

Parameter 1 ranged from a value of 12 to 10.5. Parameter 2 ranged from 18 to 3. I wanted to optimise the yield of my reaction.
I just want the final equations which can generate the relevant 3Dplot and corresponding statistical analysis of significance.

Back then, the table the software generated (and the corresponding results generated in the lab) are shown in the table below:

|Block 1|

| Parameter1 | Parameter2 | Yield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.5 | 3.0 | 5.8 |
| 10.5 | 18.0 | 6.1 |
| 11.25 | 10.5 | 7.9 |
| 11.25 | 10.5 | 8.7 |
| 11.25 | 10.5 | 11.8 |
| 12.00 | 3.0 | 4.8 |
| 12.00 | 18.0 | 8.7 |

|Block 2|

| Parameter1 | Parameter2 | Yield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.19 | 10.5 | 8.5 |
| 11.25 | 0.0 | 0.21 |
| 11.25 | 10.5 | 9.4 |
| 11.25 | 10.5 | 8.5 |
| 11.25 | 10.5 | 10.1 |
| 12.31 | 10.5 | 8.9 |
| 12.31 | 21.1 | 8.5 |

I am unable to plug these values and do the analysis even after referring to this nice tutorial: https://bookdown.org/gerhard_krennrich/doe_and_optimization/doe2.html#optimal-designs

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you provided the results of the analysis. Do you have the raw data you used? to create the results? What do the values in the unnamed columns represent? In each of the two sets of values you provided, there is one odd number. The 6th value in the first set is 6.1 11.25. The numbers work out if this is supposed to be two separate values. In the second set, the last value is 21.18.5. Is that 21.1 and 8.5?

Comment: @Kat: I have amended the table. Yes, the values are 6.1 and 11.25, and 21.1 and 8.5.
I used the DoE setup in StatEase which asked me to put the ranges I was interested in to optimise my yield. It returned me this table only filled with Parameter 1 and 2. I experimentally got values for Yield.
In other words, this is the raw data

Comment: I see a string of what should be a table. I thought I would edit your original post, so it was shown as a table. When I pressed 'edit,' it made a lot more sense than what I had thought the string looked like as a table. I am working on an answer for you now.

Comment: @Kat:I really appreciate the time you're putting into helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time trying to understand more about what I was looking at. If this isn't what you're looking for, just let me know. This should address your request for a response surface model.

I included the assumptions for RSM, as well - assuming that this is an LP.

`rsm` is the primary package used here; it stands for response surface model (method?). The package writers wrote *response surface analysis*.

Block 1 had inferior models (probably not linear); block 2 looked a lot better. All of block 1 models end with "fit"; block 2 ends with "fit2."

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rsm)
library(car)
library(plotly)

#----------------- first block ---------------------
b1 <- data.frame(
  Parameter1 = c(10.5, 10.5, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 12, 12),
  Parameter2 = c(3, 18, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 3, 18),
       Yield = c(5.8, 6.1, 7.9, 8.7, 11.8, 4.8, 8.7)
      )

names(b1) <- c("x1", "x2", "y")
# [1] "x1" "x2" "y"  

#----------- second-order model (SO) ---------------
rsm.fit <- rsm(y ~ SO(x1, x2), data = b1)
summary(rsm.fit)
```

This generated a warning in R that stated, "cannot use 'rsm' methods."
It returns an LM (linear model) object instead. You get a lot of the same information, so I left it here.

Like statease, it conducts several different models - projected in the summary. This is part of the summary:

```
# Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)    -680.3533   354.0967  -1.921    0.195
# FO(x1, x2)x1    123.5200    62.9764   1.961    0.189
# FO(x1, x2)x2     -1.6600     2.0645  -0.804    0.506
# TWI(x1, x2)       0.1600     0.1831   0.874    0.474
# PQ(x1, x2)x1^2   -5.5407     2.7970  -1.981    0.186
# PQ(x1, x2)x2^2        NA         NA      NA       NA
# 
# Residual standard error: 2.06 on 2 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7461,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.2384 
# F-statistic: 1.469 on 4 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.4433
```

I ran several other models, starting with a first-order model. This returned an RSM.

```
#--------------- first order (FO) model ------------------
# first order model
rsm2.fit <- rsm(y ~ FO(x1, x2), data = b1)
summary(rsm2.fit)

#----- first-order, 2-way interaction model (TWI) --------
rsm3.fit <- rsm(y ~ FO(x1, x2) + TWI(x1, x2), data = b1)
summary(rsm3.fit)

#----- first-order, 2-way NO interaction model -----------
rsm4.fit <- rsm(y ~ FO(x1, x2) + PQ(x1, x2), data = b1)
summary(rsm4.fit)

#-------------------- list the models --------------------
# create a list of the models to make assumption and plotting easier
fit <- list(rsm.fit = rsm.fit, 
            rsm2.fit = rsm2.fit, 
            rsm3.fit = rsm3.fit, 
            rsm4.fit = rsm4.fit)

#--------------------- assumptions -----------------------
# plot residuals
par(mfrow = c(2,2)) # four plots per page
lapply(fit, plot, which = 1:4)

#qqplot
qqPlot(rsm.fit)
qqPlot(rsm2.fit)
qqPlot(rsm3.fit)
qqPlot(rsm4.fit)

lapply(fit, cooks.distance)

#-------------------- visualize RSM -----------------------
# plot model contours
lapply(1:length(fit), function(x) {        
  contour(fit[[x]], ~ x1 + x2, image = T,
          main = paste0("Block 1: Model ", x))
})

# create base R persp and plot_ly 3D plots
  # empty lists to store plots of each model
p.fit <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(fit))   # persp plots
plt.fit <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(fit)) # plotly plots

for(i in 1:length(fit)){
  p <- persp(fit[[i]],
             x2~x1, zlab = "y",
             main = paste("Block 1: Model ", i))
  p.fit[[i]] <- p           # so you can still view persp plots
  
  x1 = p$`x1 ~ x2`$x  # for plotly
  x2 = p$`x1 ~ x2`$y
  y = p$`x1 ~ x2`$z
  
  plt.fit[[i]] <- plotly_build(
    plot_ly(x = ~x1, y = ~x2, z = ~y) %>% 
      add_surface(contours = list(
        z = list(usecolormap = T,  # create contours
                 show = T,
                 highlightcolor = "#ff0000", 
                 # highlight contour in red when hovering
                 project = list(z = T))),
        hovertemplate = paste0('x1: %{x}<br>',
                               'x2: %{y}<br>',
                               'y: %{z}<extra></extra>')) %>% 
      layout(title = list(text = paste0("Block 1: Model ", i),
                          y = .95)) # pull title down a bit
  )
}

plt.fit[[1]]
plt.fit[[2]]
plt.fit[[3]]
plt.fit[[4]]
```

Contours and Perspectives

[image]
[image]

If you haven't used Plotly before, it's very interactive.

[image]
[image]

I did this all again with the second block - the same except for the data.

```
#--------------------- 2nd Block ----------------------
b2 <- data.frame(
  Parameter1 = c(10.19, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 12.31, 12.31),
  Parameter2 = c(10.5, 0, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 21.1),
       Yield = c(8.5, 0.21, 9.4, 8.5, 10.1, 8.9, 8.5)
      )

names(b2) <- c("x1", "x2", "y")

#---------------------- SO model ----------------------
rsm.fit2 <- rsm(y ~ SO(x1, x2), data = b2)
summary(rsm.fit2)
```

There wasn't an error on the 2nd order model on block 2.

```
#---------------------- FO Model ----------------------
rsm2.fit2 <- rsm(y ~ FO(x1, x2), data = b2)
summary(rsm2.fit2)

#--------------------- FO TWI model -------------------
rsm3.fit2 <- rsm(y ~ FO(x1, x2) + TWI(x1, x2), data = b2)
summary(rsm3.fit2)

#----------------- FO NO interaction model--------------
rsm4.fit2 <- rsm(y ~ FO(x1, x2) + PQ(x1, x2), data = b2)
summary(rsm4.fit2)

#-------------------- list the models ------------------
# create a list of the models to make assumption and plotting easier
fit2 <- list(rsm.fit2 = rsm.fit2, 
             rsm2.fit2 = rsm2.fit2, 
             rsm3.fit2 = rsm3.fit2, 
             rsm4.fit2 = rsm4.fit2)

#-------------------- assumptions ----------------------
# plot residuals
lapply(fit2, plot, which = 1:4)

#qqplot
qqPlot(rsm.fit2)
qqPlot(rsm2.fit2)
qqPlot(rsm3.fit2)
qqPlot(rsm4.fit2)

# cooks distance
lapply(fit2, cooks.distance)

#-------------------- visualize RSM -----------------------
# plot model contours
lapply(1:length(fit2), function(x) {
  contour(fit2[[x]], ~ x1 + x2, image = T,
          main = paste0("Block 2: Model ", x))
})
# base R contours (scroll through plot pane to view)

# create base R persp and plot_ly 3D plots
 # empty lists to store plots of each model
p.fit2 <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(fit2))   # persp plots
plt.fit2 <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(fit2)) # plotly plots

for(i in 1:length(fit2)){
  p <- persp(fit2[[i]],
             x2~x1, zlab = "y",
             main = paste("Block 2: Model ", i))
  p.fit2[[i]] <- p           # so you can still view persp plots

  x1 = p$`x1 ~ x2`$x  # for plotly
  x2 = p$`x1 ~ x2`$y
  y = p$`x1 ~ x2`$z

  plt.fit2[[i]] <- plotly_build(
    plot_ly(x = ~x1, y = ~x2, z = ~y) %>% 
      add_surface(contours = list(
        z = list(usecolormap = T,  # create contours
                 show = T,
                 highlightcolor = "#ff0000", 
                 # highlight contour in red when hovering
                 project = list(z = T))),
        hovertemplate = paste0('x1: %{x}<br>',
                               'x2: %{y}<br>',
                               'y: %{z}<extra></extra>')) %>% 
      layout(title = list(text = paste0("Block 2: Model ", i),
                          y = .95)) # pull title down a bit
  )
}

plt.fit2[[1]]
plt.fit2[[2]]
plt.fit2[[3]]
plt.fit2[[4]]

# reset plots per page
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

Contours and Perspectives

[image]
[image]

Plotly Perspectives

[image]
[image]